# crawling with Nutch 2.3, Cassandra 2.0, and solr 4.10.3 returns 0 results

Tags: solr, cassandra, web-crawler, nutch

I mainly followed the guide on [this page](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Cassandra). I installed Nutch 2.3, Cassandra 2.0, and solr 4.10.3. Set up went well. But when I executed the following command. No urls were fetched.

```
./bin/crawl urls/seed.txt TestCrawl http://localhost:8983/solr/ 2
```

Below are my settings.

nutch-site.xml

```
http://ideone.com/H8MPcl
```

regex-urlfilter.txt

```
+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*nutch.apache.org/
```

hadoop.log

```
http://ideone.com/LnpAw4
```

I don't see any errors in the log file. I am really lost. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the regex for your website that you want to crawl in regex-urlfilter.txt to pick the link that you have added in nutch-site.xml.

Right now it will only crawl "nutch.apache.org"

Try adding below line:

```
+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*ideone.com/
```

Try to set nutch logs in debug level and get the logs while executing the crawl command.

It will clearly shows why you are unable to crawl and index the site.

Regards,

Jayesh Bhoyar

http://technical-fundas.blogspot.com/p/technical-profile.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have the seed.txt set up correctly. But it's just not returning any urls. I don't think it's the seed/regex file. I turned on debug and ran it. No errors. I did get something like an error but I don't think it caused the problem.`Failed to load native-hadoop with error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hadoop in java.library.path`

Comment: please provide more information for some one to investigate your issue.
Like full log file.
seed.txt file

Comment: Here is the full error log view online `https://www.scribd.com/doc/255695583/hadoop-full-log`. Download: `https://www.sendspace.com/file/coqie9`

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem recently. I think you can try the following steps to find out the problem.

1 Do some tests to make sure the DB works well.

2 Instead of running the crawl in batch, you can call nutch step by step and watch the log change as well as the change of DB content, in particular, the new urls.

3 Turn off solr and focus on nutch and the DB.